# Permission denied errors when working with github on windows

Tags: windows, git, github

Just two weeks ago I was coding away, making commits and pushing to github without a worry. I just got back and start working again and all of a sudden I can't make commits, push, or even pull.

Push error:

```
Unable to append to .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master: Permission Denied
Cannot update the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
```

Pull error:
    Unable to append to .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master: Permission denied

I also can't edit several files in my working directory due to "in use by another program" or read only errors, and my last commit is `Unsynced`.

I've checked file permissions and my github SSH keys, and tried my best to lookup solutions but it seems this is generally a Unix problem with user permissions and not a Windows one. I really have no idea where to keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Were you operating as the Administrator before?

Is the .git folder in a protected location?

Who owns the .git folder?

Does running a git shell as an Administrator fix the issue? (note this is not a solution, just a debugging mechanism, you shouldn't use git as root)

Comment: .git folder is not protected and my user owns it.

I may have been operating as Admin before. When I ran it as an admin and tried to commit, I got a different error than before:  

> fatal: Unable to create 'myapp/.git/refs/heads/master.lock': File exists.

Comment: I've managed to make commits using an Admin git shell after a few tweaks. I likely have been running it that way the whole time. Do you know how I could change the file ownership to my user instead?

Answer (score 0):

> `.git` folder is not protected and my user owns it. I may have been operating as Admin before.

Git 2.37.3 (Q3 2022) illustrates how "having been operating as Admin before" can have consequences.

The platform-specific code that determines if a directory is OK to use as a repository has been taught to report more details, especially on Windows.

See [commit 3f7207e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f7207e2ea967fd2b46d9e0ae85246e93b38ed58), [commit 7c83470](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c83470e64eadab74689427fcd95e72f0a772ab5), [commit e883e04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e883e04b68ba7393029bcbeaa2aacb3dff5d3fbd), [commit 17d3883](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17d3883fe9c88b823002ad9fafb42313ddc3d3d5), [commit d51e1df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d51e1dff980b9fc87002436b6ab36120a39816b1) (08 Aug 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7fac7b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fac7b563b0d4f174b30bfbedab67e59af8cce84), 14 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e883e04b68ba7393029bcbeaa2aacb3dff5d3fbd): provide details about unsafe directories' ownership
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When Git refuses to use an existing repository because it is owned by someone else than the current user, it can be a bit tricky on Windows to figure out what is going on.
>
> Let's help with that by providing more detailed information.

The message will now be:

```
"a/path is owned by:
'xxx'
but the current user is:
'yyy'
```

Your issue should however be mitigated:

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f7207e2ea967fd2b46d9e0ae85246e93b38ed58): handle a file owned by the Administrators group correctly
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> When an `Administrator` creates a file or directory, the created file/directory is owned not by the `Administrator` SID, but by the *`_Administrators` Group* SID.
> The reason is that users with administrator privileges usually run in unprivileged ("non-elevated") mode, and their user SID does not change when running in elevated mode.
>
> This is is relevant e.g. when running a GitHub workflow on a build agent, which runs in elevated mode: cloning a Git repository in a script step will cause the worktree to be owned by the Administrators Group SID, for example.
>
> Let's handle this case as following:
>
> If the current user is an administrator, Git should consider a worktree owned by the `Administrators` Group as if it were owned by said user.

On Windows, no more "permission denied" when you are user `xxx` (who is also admin) using a folder originally created and owned by "`Administrator`".